# Failed to find geo_point field location Springframework Data Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Failed to find geo_point field location. The location field should have geo_point in mapping but getting lat, lon.

**Model Class:**

```
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.GeoPointField;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.geo.GeoPoint;

class EsMapping extends TestIndex{
@GeoPointField
private GeoPoint location;
@Field(type = FieldType.Double)
private double latitude;
@Field(type = FieldType.Double)
private double longitude;
.
.
```

}

**TestIndex.java**

```
class TestIndex{
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String name;
    .
    .
}
```

**Test Controller**

```
@Autowired
private ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchOperations;

IndexOperations esMappingIndex = 
elasticsearchOperations.indexOps(EsMapping.class);
esMappingIndex.delete();
esMappingIndex.create();
esMappingIndex.putMapping(esMappingIndex.createMapping());
esMappingIndex.refresh();
```

**Mapping:** (not expected)
http://localhost:9200/testindex/_mapping

```
"location": {
                "properties": {
                    "lat": {
                        "type": "float"
                    },
                    "lon": {
                        "type": "float"
                    }
                }
            },
"latitude": {
                "type": "float"
            },
"longitude": {
                "type": "float"
            },
```

**Error:**

```
    {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to find geo_point field [location] ","index_uuid":"QLCjshecRNqDMXtkrtbF9g","index":"testindex"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"testindex","node":"jCKzz88BQXeL3wzyX6c8lQ","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to find geo_point field [location]","index_uuid":"QLCjshecRNqDMXtkrtbF9g","index":"testindex"}}]},"status":400}
```

**Expected Mapping**

```
"location": {
                "type": "geo_point"
            },
"latitude": {
                "type": "double"
            },
"longitude": {
                "type": "double"
            },
```

Comment: can you please provide the complete entity definition and some more context when this error happens?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch Thanks for the reply, I have added the expected mapping and controller class code in question.

Answer (score 0):

When I define entity properties like above - with an index name *geopoint-test* - and do execute the mapping creating code (which is executed as well on application startup), I get the following mapping:

```json
{
    "geopoint-test": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "location": {
                    "type": "geo_point"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are two differences to the mapping you show:

1. the `location` propert is mapped correctly
2. the `latitude` and `longitude` properties are not written to the mapping, as they are not annotated with `@Field` and so are left for automatic mapping.

The mapping you show is the one that will be automatically created.

Which version of Spring Data Elasticsearch are you using?

**Edit 12.12.2020:**

Using Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0.2 and adding the two `@Field` annotations to the `latitude`and `longitude` properties, both the initial setup of an index and the code to explicitly write the mapping produce this mapping:

```json
{
    "properties": {
        "location": {
            "type": "geo_point"
        },
        "latitude": {
            "type": "double"
        },
        "longitude": {
            "type": "double"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Spring Data Elasticsearch version: 2.3.2.RELEASE

Comment: There never was a version 2.3.2 of Spring Data Elasticsearch.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am extending TestIndex class in EsMapping, I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: I'm using Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0.2 version

Comment: I tried this with 4.0.2, see my edit. Are there any erros in the log when you try to write the mapping?